# Datepicker and timepicker not showing in Modal with remote data

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried as suggested to change the z-index of .datepicker but it doesn't help. the get_status view is loaded correctly and passing the params but datepicker and time picker are not prompting. Just to note the section from which the modal is generated is itself an ajax refreshed div. I am using Bootstrap v3.3.7

whole code:
https://paste.laravel.io/337a1852-7051-42dc-902b-ee70c495ae9c

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-href="get_status/35/failed" class="basic">Schedule</a>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.basic').on('click',function(){
        var dataURL = $(this).attr('data-href');
        $('.modal-body').load(dataURL,function(){
            $('#basic').modal({show:true});
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize datepicker after result getting loaded i mean init datepicker inside load callback of you ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.basic').on('click',function(){
        var dataURL = $(this).attr('data-href');
        $('.modal-body').load(dataURL,function(){
            $('#basic').modal({show:true});
/*************Init Datepicker/TimePicker here *******************/
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks this is working, only thing is formatting the timepicker to 24 Hours  . this doesn't work :  $('.timepicker').timepicker({format: 'HH:mm'});
        });
    });
</script>

Comment: Which timepicker you are using that is depends on its options refer documentation there will be option for setting up time format

Comment: thanks got it solved with  $('.timepicker-24').timepicker({
                    autoclose: true,
                    minuteStep: 5,
                    showSeconds: false,
                    showMeridian: false
                });